# Rocky Linux 9 not accepting SFTP connections from old Dreamweaver version (no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss)

Tags: centos, ssh, security, sftp, key-authentication

Running `Rocky Linux 9` on server and I am trying to connect **by password, not by key**...
It works when connecting with Putty on port 22, but when I try to connect with an old Dreamweaver version, selecting SFTP and port 22, it doesn't connect, and on server's `/var/log/secure` I see:

```
sshd[23594]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
sshd[23612]: Unable to negotiate with [my IP] port 64671: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
```

Connecting with Filezilla over SFTP also works fine.

I seen there are many replies to similar issues but most of them refer to connecting using a private key, in my case I want it to also work with a password and I don't want to edit the wrong files.

So what should I edit on server in order to tell it to accept this older connection mode ? On client side (Dreamweaver) there aren't many/any options.

Comment: in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` change `HostKeyAlgorithms` if it exists to add at least one of ssh-rsa or ssh-dss. If only the latter, also generate `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key{,.pub}` if necessary; recent OpenSSH may not do so automatically; to avoid this complication use ssh-rsa. If `HostKeyAlgorithms` doesn't exist already I'm pretty sure you can add it without knowing the default using the syntax `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`; if not, get the server's version of OpenSSH and I'll look up the default.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, I didn't find the option so I added it at the end of the file then restarted `sshd`. What did work was this (I added it as an answer): `update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY` and `reboot` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer on a [centos forum topic](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=79687).

First, this shows what crypto-policy is currently set:

```
update-crypto-policies --show
```

Then to activate "LEGACY" policy:

```
update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```

and a **reboot**. Done.

The manuals that explains the policies:

```
man update-crypto-policies
man crypto-policies
```

Comment: This is downgrading the security of the server, good if it suits you. Gentle reminder for future readers, you might want to upgrade your obsolete SSH/SCP/SFTP client software instead of doing this.